# request.session undefined . nodeJS express

Tags: node.js, session, express

there were many questions about this topic around , but none could solve my problem , 
i developed an express app and my authentication method was to write to session object and using redis-store . it worked perfect during development ,

but the first time i deployed my site for some tests ( using modulus ) i get an error that req.session is undefined . the code still works fine when i run this on localhost .

this is actually my first web project and there were so many obvious points and tricks that i didn't know and had to learn through the way . maybe i'm missing something simple and obvious here , don't know !

**package.josn dependencies :**

```
  "dependencies" : {
        "express"    : "~3.4.4",
        "mongoose"   : "~3.6.2",
          "socket.io":"1.x" ,
        "bcrypt-nodejs" : "0.0.3",
        "connect-redis": "1.4.x" ,
        "body-parser" : "1.4.3" ,
        "cookie-parser": "~1.0.0",
        "express-session": "~1.0.0"
    } ,
```

**app configuration**

```
var express = require('express') ;
var app = express() ;
var http = require('http') ;
var io = require('socket.io') ;
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose') ;
var mongoose1 = require('mongoose') ;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs') ;
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080 ;
var server = http.createServer(app) ;
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static" )) ;
    app.use( express.cookieParser() );
    app.use(express.bodyParser()) ;
    app.use(express.session({
        store: new RedisStore({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 6379,
            db: 2,
            pass: '****'
        }),
        secret: '12345qwr'
    })
    );

}) ;
```

and when i reach req.session.[] in my server , app crashed and restarts because req.session in undefined . 
for example when I click on a login button and a post request is sent to "/api/login" or ..

```
    app.post('/api/login' , function (req, res) {
        UserDBModel.findOne({ username : req.body.user } , function (err, user) {
            if (err) { res.json(err) ; }
            if ( user ) {
                if ( bcrypt.compareSync( req.body.pass ,  user.password ) ) {
                    req.session.Auth = { username : user.username , password : user.password } ;
//app crashes here with error : TypeError: Cannot set property 'Auth' of undefined

    }) ;
```

ps. to authenticate , i store an "Auth" object in my session containing username and hashed password of logged in users .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `app.use(express.session(` try to use: `app.use(express.cookieSession());` then the `request.session` object will be accessible...

Comment: I have searched for the answer to this problem for a while now, every solution did not work for me because in most every other instance of this problem the coder was coding it such that the res object would respond to the client before setting the variable. This was not the case for me at all, this seems to do the job well, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you are running the redis service

```
sudo service redis-server start
```