# Express req.body undefined, routes after bodyParser doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express

I have no idea why in programming there are so many damn errors and issues even for basic tasks. Here is my code, it refuses to work no matter how many wacky positional changes I make.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var store = require('./routes/store');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('home', {title: 'Ninja Store'})
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    username = req.body.username || 'Anonymous';
    req.session.username = username;
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

It keeps saying

```
Cannot set property 'username' of undefined
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: check properly I think it's failing on line `req.session.username = username;`

Comment: My friend you are completely right! Thanks for pointing that out. Now to figure out whats going wrong with session.

Comment: I think you are not using `session` middleware.

Comment: have a look here after that let me know https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-session

Comment: Mritunjay, yeah you are right, I found express-session with some simple googling. I think it was once included as a part of expressjs which is why the tutorial I am following doesn't indicate I need to manually install it. Thanks for the help buddy!

Comment: added as an answer fot your probelm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here the `req.session` is undefined, not `req.body`. Because it's **property setting error.**

If it `req.body` will be undefined it will throw error of **property reading**.

```
Cannot read property 'username' of undefined.
```

You should use [express-session](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-session) middleware to overcome this problem. I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I've already answered very same question [check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930864/request-session-undefined-nodejs-express/24932495#24932495) you should just use: `app.use(express.cookieSession());`